# https certificate issue

Tags: c#, .net, iis, visual-studio-2008, iis-7

I need to use some certificate on IIS 7.0 web server to test my https code at client side (console application). I have created self-signed certificate and it is fine. Now I want to test with formal certificate which IE could recognize, like certificates from verisign or other formal certificate issuing companies.

Any easy way to get some free and formal certificate? I only need to test for a few days.

I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + IIS 7.0.

Here is what verisign returns when I create a free trial certificate, I am not sure what is wrong?

```
Error 950e - Invalid Common Name Error The common name in the CSR contains invalid characters like '?', '*', ':', ' '.  

If you continue to receive this error or have further questions, you may write to support@verisign.com for assistance. Please include the following information in your correspondence:


Product or service you are enrolling for
Your server software vendor (for server certificates)
Common Name of your certificate (for example, www.verisign.com)
URL where you are experiencing this error message.
```

Comment: what is it that you cannot test with the self-signed cert?

Comment: @handsomGun - usually, that it is going to work on a vanilla user's/customer's computer ;-p

Comment: Verisign has a "Free SSL Trial" offer available

Comment: I am testing Silverlight client, Silverlight cannot bypass certificate verification as we did in console application which continues to show error message.

Comment: @Anand, I have tried but always something wrong. I have posted my error information, any ideas what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This has been manually reposted on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/64415/https-certificate-issue

Answer (score 2):

> Any easy way to get some free and formal certificate?

While some root CAs might be cheaper I don't think any are free.

If you want free you could set up your own CA (Windows Server has one) and add its self signed certificate to you trusted roots in your Windows user profile (which IE uses). Firefox (and I assume other) browsers have their own certificate stores and need to have the root CA installed.

Comment: Thanks, any guide to setup CA on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Quite a lot on Technet, but I found it largely self explanitory (but then I understood the basics of how public key certificates work already). Here is a start: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755290.aspx

Comment: This is about summary for root CA on Windows, what I need is a step by step guide about how to setup root CA on Windows Server 2008, any recommended readings?

Comment: Technet search finds lots of possibility, but I just did it (not hard). Here are some potential links: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=install%20standalone%20certificate%20server&ac=8

Answer (score 1):

try adding your self signed certificate to you trusted roots, that should be accepted. i don't know about silverlight, but it worked fine for a .net web service client i did the other day.

Comment: "try adding your self signed certificate to you trusted roots" -- I double click and install the certificate, but still IE has warning message. Maybe I am wrong for the installtion? How to install self-signed certificate as trusted roots?

Comment: you have the cert already, so you can start with step 2.)

http://wp.dembowski.net/2007/07/21/importing-self-signed-ssl-certs-into-vista/

Answer (score 0):

https://letsencrypt.org/ will allows you to get free browser valid ssl certificate for an https connection to your server